# Groups with cardinality larger than the Reals in physics

Tags: mathematical-physics, group-theory, mathematics

In what physical theories are sets with cardinality larger than $\aleph_1$ used? There are plenty of examples of finite, countable, and uncountable vector spaces in physics, but do physicists ever invoke "larger" groups?

Comment: Path integrals are over the "space of all functions". Does that count? In any case, this is list-based and typically considered too-broad.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00668838

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransforn, how would one quantify the cardinality of the space of all paths?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform - The space of all functions would count as it has cardinality $\aleph_2$. But the space of all continuous functions has cardinality $\aleph_1$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477/cardinality-of-set-of-real-continuous-functions and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-real-functions-of-real-variable. These links are for 1D real functions, but it generalizes to 3D complex functions.

Comment: @mmesser314, thanks, that pretty much answers my question

Comment: *"The space of all functions [has] cardinality $\aleph_2$. But the space of all continuous functions has cardinality $\aleph_1$."* And the moral of today's lesson, students, is that infinities are weird.

Comment: @dcmkee - Not so weird. A general fcn on [0,1] can have any value at each point. The number of such functions is R x R. A continuous function on [0,1] can be characterized by Fourier coefficients. There can't be more than 1 for each possible frequency. The cardinality cannot exceed R. Continuity is a powerful constraint.

Comment: @mmesser314, is that because the allowed Fourier frequencies on a finite interval must be countable?

Comment: A frequency must be a real number, which means they can be uncountable. Countable frequencies are usually multiples of a base frequency, which makes the function periodic. If you use an uncountable set of frequencies, you can get a non-periodic function. I am not sure how that plays out on [0,1], which can obviously be extended to a periodic function. So maybe I should not have used it. The set of periodic functions is uncountable. Even though the number of Fourier coefficients is countable, the values are any real number.

Comment: I know this is old but I just bumped into it.  Note that the cardinality of the reals is $2^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1$.  Whether or not this is the same as $\aleph_1$ is the Continuum Hypothesis which is proven to be unprovable (in the common ZFC axions).